# Replacing div after countdown timer div

Tags: javascript, html

How do I replace a javascript countdown div to a new div. I have try hidden it's visibility but it seems don't work on replacing a new div

```js
// Set the date we're counting down to
var countDownDate = new Date("Sep 16, 2017 16:22:00").getTime();

// Update the count down every 1 second
var x = setInterval(function() {

  // Get todays date and time
  var now = new Date().getTime();

  // Find the distance between now an the count down date
  var distance = countDownDate - now;

  // Time calculations for days, hours, minutes and seconds
  var days = Math.floor(distance / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));
  var hours = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24)) / (1000 * 60 * 60));
  var minutes = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60)) / (1000 * 60));
  var seconds = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60)) / 1000);

  // Output the result in an element with id="demo"
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = days + "d " + hours + "h " +
    minutes + "m " + seconds + "s ";

  // If the count down is over, write some text 
  if (distance < 0) {
    clearInterval(x);
    document.querySelector("#div1").style.display = "block";
    document.getElementById("demo").style.visibility = "hidden";

  }
}, 1000);
```

```css
#demo {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 60px;
}

#div1 {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 60px;
}
```

```html
<div id="demo"></div>
<div id="div1" style="display:none;">
  <p>Hello</p>
</div>
```

but I want to replace it to this div

```html
<div id="div1" style="display:none;" ><p>Hello</p></div>
```

Comment: Why mix the selectors?
`document.getElementById("div1").style.display = "block";
    document.getElementById("demo").style.display = "none";
`

Comment: https://www.sitepoint.com/build-javascript-countdown-timer-no-dependencies/